# Uncaught TypeError: navigator.webkitGetUserMedia is not a function

Tags: node.js, webrtc, videochat

I want to build video chatting website using WebRTC. I am using chrome chrome 83.0.4103.97. I have followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieBtXwHvoNk for this. But got the error in my browser. My code and error is below

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false}, function(stream){
//
}, function(err){
    console.error(err)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `navigator.getUserMedia`

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
```

now you can use it as

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false}, function(stream){
 }, function(err){
 console.error(err)
})
```

Comment: @TanmonyMajumdar, thank you for your answer. I have solved this problem by running on localhost. I have run this on my own ip_address. I knew later only on localhost or https:// can allow webcam or microphone in google chrome. Thanks.